# How can I make a background overlaying the recyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, background, background-color

I have a horizontal recyclerView of images. I want to set a background color that covers the recyclerView.

I want to:

[image]

I made with my xml code:
[image]

I've added a view to the RecyclerView area. Background color gave it there. When I write it like this in the code, the background color is under the recyclerView:

gradient background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:centerColor="#f1f1f1"
        android:endColor="#FFF8F8F6"
        android:startColor="@color/white" />

</shape>
```

xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomView"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

        <View
        android:id="@+id/bottomView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/images"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/images"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/images"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/images"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/images"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/images"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_white"  />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sendButton"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="14dp"
            android:scaleType="center"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_send_24" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/images"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35980486/android-recyclerview-backgroundcolor/35981154

Comment: No it is different. I want to cover background

Comment: what does that mean? please elaborate

Comment: please see my edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all rearrange order of your `View`s - first should be `RecyclerView`, then covering background, then send icon. `View`s placed in XML are drawn in order of declaration, treat them like layers in your case (and for the future: be aware of `translationZ` and `elevation` XML attributes)

and for placing covering "background" `View` (in fact this is foreground, "above" `RecyclerView`) use this:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/images" ....

<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#80FFFFFF"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/images"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/images"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/images"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/images"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/sendButton" ...
```

"covering" `View` may have `0dp` size for better measuring performance, still all `android:layout_align...` declarations make it stretch to the size of `RecyclerView` (and as later-declared this `View` will be drawn after `RecyclerView`, so on top of it)

just adjust your `android:background`, use some [gradient drawable with transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823607/how-to-make-transparent-gradient)

edit: gradient drawable file (put in `drawable` folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient
    android:startColor="#00ffffff"
    android:centerColor="#00ffffff"
    android:centerY="80%"
    android:endColor="#fff"
    android:angle="0"
    android:dither="true"/>
</shape>
```

set it up as

```
android:background="@drawable/your_file_name_of_above_shape"
```

Comment: please help me for background gradient color

Comment: you have a link to whole topic how to set it up... declaration is posted in question, use only `startColor` and `endColor` (ommit `centerColor`) - one of these two should be transparent, second one should be white

Comment: Yeap I know but I but I can't match the colors exactly. I added it to my edited code. Can you help me

Comment: And this layout still didn't cover

Comment: added sample gradient declaration, show some screen how it currently looks

Comment: thank you but still my recyclerView items are visible not covering

Comment: update your code in question and I will inspect what may be wrong

Comment: my answer starts with "first of all" and you didn't fixed improper order... first must be `RecyclerView`, then covering `View` (with gradient drawable), at last send `ImageView`. just like in my answer...